# How do I make a custom subdomain on Firebase?

Tags: dns, subdomain, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have purchased a domain ("www.mydomain.com"). How do I make a subdomain on Firebase ("sub.mydomain.com"), if I am using Firebase hosting?

Comment: FYI, you purchased mydomain.com.  Anything below that is up to you - dougliu.mydomain.com, www.mydomain.com, what.ever.mydomain.com are all things you control.

Answer (score 40):

**Update**

You can now add multiple domains to a single Firebase Hosting site. Domains can either serve site content or redirect to another domain (editable at any time). In addition, you can now use subdomains of the same registered domain on different projects, such as example.com on one project and blog.example.com on another. Visit your [hosting admin page](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/hosting/main) to configure them.

**Original answer**

If you point multiple subdomains of `mydomain.com` to Firebase Hosting, it will redirect others to the one you chose when specifying your custom domain. If you're looking to simply serve content from one subdomain, all you need do is specify that one in the custom domain field on you Hosting tab and point your DNS for that subdomain to Firebase Hosting, following the instructions provided.

If, however, you're looking to serve different content on different subdomains, that's not currently possible, though this is a highly requested feature that we're considering implementing

Comment: Hey @Chris, Please do the different content on different subdomains feature asap :D any updates there?

Comment: Firebase Hosting fully supports apex domains - you can specify an apex domain instead of a subdomain when setting the custom domain, and Firebase Hosting will redirect all subdomains to the apex. We'll provide the A-Record entries you'll need to set up an apex domain, and you can choose between A-Records or a CNAME for the subdomains

Comment: @Chris with the new firebase update is it possible to point different apps to different subdomains?

Comment: No, it's still not possible. It's something we understand users really want and we would love to offer, but I'm afraid can't share any time frames for when it might be ready

Comment: @Chris This is a must have feature, as our application relies on custom subdomains to determine the user sub set/account. We're now forced to look for other hosting elsewhere unfortunately, which is a pity because I love the simplicity of Firebase.

Comment: @kato Are there published instructions on how to make this work? Jose's answer above doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 12):

i believe you can use rewritte rules on the hosting configuration json file

since all domains and subdomains you point to your firebase project will be redirected to your single firebase hosting bucket, youll need to set up custom rewrite rules for each domain you want to separate, to redirect them to an specific folder or cloud function in your project.

i suggest to check the next url as reading material, its a new techinque to work with projects in firebase 
https://github.com/jthegedus/firebase-functions-next-example

on your firebase.json file

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/.well-known/assetlinks.json",
        "destination": "/instant/assetlinks.json"
      },
      {
        "source": "sub.domain.com/**",
        "destination": "/subdomain/**"
      }
    ]
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  }
}
```