# Multi tenancy in firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to use firebase with different subdomains, but serving the same content.

I've managed to redirect subdomains, but I need to stay routed to it.

When I type for exemple: subdomain.mydomain.com, I'm being redirected to mydomain.com.
I need it to stay on subdomain.mydomain.com.

The subdomain will be created dynamically.

Comment: As you've already discovered, it redirects to the root domain, so this isn't possible.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147602/how-do-i-make-a-custom-subdomain-on-firebase

Answer (score 1):

For reference, see the answer from Chris at [How do I make a custom subdomain on Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147602/how-do-i-make-a-custom-subdomain-on-firebase)

As it stands this is not currently possible, although it seems to be an often requested feature that they are working on.

Comment: Fyi we've moved away from Firebase to Netlify because this wasn't supported.