# Multiple apps pointing to different subdomains on Firebase

Tags: firebase, subdomain, firebase-hosting

I've already configured my domain in firebase "mydomain.com" pointing to "myapp.firebaseapp.com" and its working fine.

But what i want now is to setup subdomains, like "develop.mydomain.com" to point to another firebase app like "develop.firebaseapp.com".

As i've already seen from [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/6_2oI4RpYdo) this it not possible because of the SSL certificate, that points to "*.mydomain.com"

But in this same thread, he said that it's possible to setup like google does *mail.google.com* and *maps.google.com*, pointing them to a subtree on the same hosted app. This is the part that i don't know how to do...

Is it possible to setup subdomains on the same hosted app to point to different applications on firebase? If so, how?

PS: I have a hosted zone in amazon to configure this domain.

Comment: With one domain (xyz.com) you can only have a single Firebase project, even if you use subdomains. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147602/how-do-i-make-a-custom-subdomain-on-firebase