# I want to set firebase two subdomain

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have two firebase project.

so i want domain setting project1.domain.com, project2.domain.com

project1.domain.com setting ok.

but second project project2.domain.com get message "exist domain"

is it impossible?

thank you for your time.

Comment: A single domain can indeed only be tied to a single app. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147602/how-do-i-make-a-custom-subdomain-on-firebase

Comment: thank you for your answer  Frank van Puffelen