# How to use multiple sub-domains from the same root for deploying apps?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to deploy my apps to Firebase but having some issues with pointing custom sub-domains.

Say my root domain is **example.com** and I have deployed my first app successfully using a sub-domain **app-01.example.com**.

Now I want to deploy another app to **app-02.example.com**. However when I try to do this, I'm getting the error "This domain is already in use".

I wasn't able to find much on this issue, it appears that it has something to do with the SSL certificates and if that's the case we'll need a different root domain for each app we're deploying. Are there any workarounds or am I missing something?

Comment: Only a single subdomain can be hosted on Firebase at the moment. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147602/how-do-i-make-a-custom-subdomain-on-firebase

Comment: Yes, that explains the situation.

Comment: You can now add multiple domains to a single Firebase Hosting site. Domains can either serve site content or redirect to another domain (editable at any time). In addition, you can now use subdomains of the same registered domain on different projects, such as example.com on one project and blog.example.com on another. Visit your [hosting admin page](https://firebase.corp.google.com/project/_/hosting/main) to configure them.