# How deploy two app on the same domain firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Lets say I have application on `example.firebaseapp.com` for public users and I want to deploy another admin app on the same doamin but with different subdomain, for example `admin.example.firebaseapp.com`. Is it possible?

Comment: You can currently only have one app on each domain. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147602/how-do-i-make-a-custom-subdomain-on-firebase