# Firebase hosting as a subfolder of the full website

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

In Firebase everything is divided into projects. I am making games so logically each game should be one project.

Now I would like to host a static page for each games. I think it is a good idea to use the Hosting menu in each projects but however the website should be under the same game developer company website.

In the connecting domain section I only see the option to connect the hosted site to either root domain or subdomain. Connecting to root is no good since this is not the only game I have and I already have a landing page of my company, so the option for me is to use the subdomain as `mygame.companyname.com`

But I am moving to Firebase from somewhere else (AWS S3 static web hosting) and I have been using `companyname.com/mygame` for long time. Is there a way to make the hosted site appears as a subfolder like that instead of a subdomain? Currently in AWS, when I update the game site I can use AWS command line to sync to just the game subfolder. In Firebase's command line, using `deploy` means uploading everything to the root.

I might need an another Firebase project just for hosting the `companyname.com` so that all my games can connect to it. But that's ok.

Comment: Each subdomain on Firebase Hosting will require a separate Firebase project. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147602/how-do-i-make-a-custom-subdomain-on-firebase. Aside from that, you should simply create the folder structure you need on your local disk and then publish that using `firebase deploy`. So if you need a `mygame` subdirectory for `mygame`, create said directory under the root and deploy.

Comment: Note that I prefer not to use subdomain because I have already marketed the folder structure style domain in many places and want to keep using it. The problem is if I create the folder structure, that folder would have to start at my main company's website for the Game A to be a subfolder of that. If I do this, I won't be able to use Game B Hosting section since Game B would already have been included in Game A's `deploy` command. And moreover doesn't updating company website via Game A project page seems odd?

Comment: The common approach to different hosting locations is to use different subdomains, i.e. gamea.companyname.com. In solutions I know of, a single (sub)domain is mapped to a single hosting provider. You can often within that provider point to a different location on disk (e.g. with server-side rewrites), but having subdirectories map to different providers would be new to me.