# How to add a subdomain using Firebase and Namecheap?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, namecheap

I am trying to add a subdomain for my firebase app but it is not working. I've looked at Firebase site's [Subdomain setup](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/hosting/dns/subdomain) and this other SO post [How do I make a custom subdomain on Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147602/how-do-i-make-a-custom-subdomain-on-firebase) but they didn't really help me.

I have a firebase app that is currently running: myawesomesite.com. I have ***another*** firebase app that I want to create the subdomain for awesome.myawesomesite.com.

I own the domain name myawesomesite.com via Namecheap. myawesomesite.com has been up for over a year.

Here is what it looks like on Firebase Hosting for the `awesome` app:

[image: firebase hosting dashboard showing the google sites and custom URL that is pending]

It has been showing "Needs setup" for the past 4 days.

Went I went through "Add custom domain", Firebase verified myawesomesite.com domain. Then I told Firebase that I wanted awesome.myawesomesite.com. Firebase then gave me two A Record values:

[image: add custom domain popup]

I also noticed that the A Record values for my subdomain request (awesome.myawesomesite.com), 123.456.7.890, are exactly the same A Record values for my domain myawesomesite.com.

This is what it looks like on my Namecheap dashboard:

[image: namecheap Advanced DNS]

I am pretty sure I did something wrong because Firebase give the same A Record values for both my domain (myawesomesite.com) and my subdomain (awesome.myawesomesite.com). I expected them to have different values. But Firebase gave me those values when I'm on my awesome project requesting for "Add custom domain". It has been 4 days and awesome.myawesomesite.com hasn't been active yet.

How can I correctly add a subdomain awesome.myawesomesite.com using namecheap and firebase hosting? Is this even possible on Firebase in 2021?

Comment: Incorrect assumption: `I expected them to have different values.` The values can be the same. The distinction is made via the HTTP Host header.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same task at hand and proceeded as follows:

1. In Firebase console, click to add a new custom domain to your hosting project and enter the subdomain with main-domain. E.g. 'sub.domain.com'.
2. Copy the value ("google-site-verification=something").
3. In Namecheap, go to the advanced DNS menu and add a new TXT record.

- Host*: @
- Value: google-site-verification=something

4. Save and wait for 5~15 minutes.
5. Back in Firebase Hosting, click to verify your domain. (If not ready yet, try again until verified).
   **After this, Firebase gave me *one* A record. Not two as normally stated in the docs! Might be because it is the year 2023, or because it is a subdomain, or both.**
6. Enter this record in Namecheap.

- Host: the subdomain name you want to use (e.g. sub)
- Value: the address Firebase gave you (e.g. 111.222.333.444).
- I did **not(!)** delete any other A or AAAA record as stated in the docs or the Firebase console.

8. Save and wait for 1~24 hours. Your subdomain should now be verified and activated.

*I usually saw docs and help desk entries that state, that for a subdomain, the TXT record's Host value should include the subdomain (e.g. only "sub", or "sub.domain.com", etc.), but that didn't work for me, so I changed it to "@" and got verified shortly after.